# I want to select rows which has a particular value in the column but the column can contain multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
col_1   col_2
0       ab,bc,cd
1       bc,xy
2       zz,xx
3       ab
4       cc
5       ef,kk,ok
```

I want to select rows that have "ab" as one of the values in col_2. For example - in this case, 0th and 3rd row will be selected.
So, is there any SQL query for that?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is just a misuse of strings.  The correct data model would have a separate row for each `col_1`/`col_2` combination.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad decisions on data modeling.  MySQL actually has a function to help deal with this, `find_in_set()`.

You can use:

```
where find_in_set('ab', col_2) > 0
```

until you fix the data model.